# Code that Track the Last Added Item on cart

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, cart-rule

I would like to ask about the way to track the last item added on the cart. I don't want to switch the product I just want to track it and display it on the error handling of the Cart. How would I do it?

Note: I only allow a single product on cart and disregard the last item added if not same with the product on the cart.

Answer (score 1):

Just two line code for that

> $collection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
>
> echo $collection->getLastItem()->getName();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code works on an empty cart only.

Comment: Above code will display last added product name. If cart is empty then it will display nothing actually.

Comment: but when I got an item on the cart same product is being showed not the last added product.

Comment: Don't know why, but it should work in each case. Check once in private window. You could use that code in any phtml

Comment: I did use it and it is working but not just I wanted it to be,.

Comment: If you need more info about the last item, then you could use getData()

Comment: but is it really possible to track the last item added on the cart considering the current rule of the cart is ONE ITEM ONLY?

Comment: Is there any rule as cart can have only one item?

Comment: That would be the case since any collection of data on the cart only shows  a single product even if I add another one.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the last item in the cart with below code

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
            $last = 0;
            $lastItem = null;
            foreach ($items as $item){
                if ($item->getId() > $last) {
                    $last = $item->getId();
                    $lastItem = $item; 
$_product = $lastItem->getProduct();
                echo $xproductsku = $_product->getName();

                }
            }
            if ($lastItem){
                $_product = $lastItem->getProduct();
                echo $xproductsku = $_product->getName();

            }
 ?>
```

Comment: Can this be put on the .phtml code? I do think the product last added is being rejected by the Observer or Something. Sorry but I am new with Magento.

Comment: yes you can put in phtml.

Comment: I see. I will try is first. I will mark it solve when it is working on my site.

Comment: It is correct on the empty cart but not when I add a different product.

Comment: i test it is working on adding the product too. last product i added it's shows

Comment: Note: I only allow a single product on cart and disregard the last item added if not same with the product on the cart.

Comment: cart is showing the last item added on top..

Comment: Same sku is being showed on the current item on the cart whenever I add a new product.

Comment: try updated code it is tested too and working perfectly.

Comment: Maybe because of the the code doesn't allow a collection of Items. Could it be?

Comment: magento use the session if you try to `foreach ($items as $item){
                if ($item->getId() > $last) {
                    $last = $item->getId();
                    echo $lastItem = $item; 
                }
            }` you can see you are getting all item.

Comment: It displays nothing.

Comment: updating the answer check you are getting all cart item?

Comment: I did update the code. Even I add another item it only display the item currently on the cart.

Comment: did the page is reloading after adding the cart? because it is using the session and session need to reload the to update.

Comment: When ever I add an item it is from the Product Page > Onepage Checkout Page. Not sure what are you trying to get...